# subset sum divisible in two groups with equal elements

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

[Problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CWC2015/): Given an array of size N, is it possible to divide the array into two groups of exactly N/2 elements each such that the sum of elements in both the groups are equal?

What I tried: use the concept of subset sum where `dp[i][j]` is true if `j` elements can sum up to `i`. In the end the answer would be `dp[sum/2][len(array)/2]`.

```
def equal_subset(a):
  s = sum(a)
  if len(a)%2 != 0 or s%2 != 0:
    return False
  dp = [[0 for j in range(len(a)+1)] for i in range(s+1)]
  dp[0][0] = 1
  for i in range(1, s/2+1):
    for j in range(1, (len(a)+1)):
      dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1]
      if i >= a[j-1]:
        dp[i][j] = dp[i][j] or dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1]
  return dp[s/2][len(a)/2]

print(equal_subset([2, 10, 20, 4, 5, 23]))
```

Some [folks](https://www.quora.com/Given-an-array-of-size-N-is-it-possible-to-divide-the-array-into-two-groups-of-exactly-N-2-elements-each-such-that-the-sum-of-elements-in-both-the-groups-are-equal#!n=12) are using dp with bitmasking as below:
`dp[i]` gives you the bitmask of possible numbers of players that can make up a team with total experience `i`. To add 1 to each of the possible numbers of players for a given total experience, shift left by 1. To merge two sets of numbers, just take the bitwise OR.

```
dp[i] |= dp[i-array[j]] << 1
```

In the end the answer will be `dp[sum/2][len(array)/2]`

Question: In both of the approaches, I think the time complexity would be the same, except in the second approach you will get better space complexity. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Two approaches are only differed in the way they represent array `dp`. You can even change your `dp` into boolean array, what is your concern?

Comment: @PhamTrung: Just wanted to check the complexity analysis of both and why one would be better than other.

Comment: Because for bitmask solution, for each state `dp[i][j]`, it only needs a single bit to represent the state, rather than using a whole integer (32 bit) to represent the state as you use in `dp[i][j]`.